# Xcode 10 & Xcode 11 Code Completion shows all objects as "int *"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, intellisense, code-completion

I'm having a problem where autocomplete simply doesn't show up. For example, if I try accessing a window's `rootViewController`, the Intellisense view doesn't even appear. If I press Control-Space, all that appears is a tiny view which reads, "No Completions."

[image]

On the previous symbol, in this example, the `window` property on my object, Intellisense appears, but it identifies the property as being of type `int *`.

[image]

I have done all of the obvious things (perform a clean, clear derived data, restart Xcode, reboot device) but the issue persists.

I've found several pages (both StackOverflow and articles elsewhere) about similar, though not identical, issues and have yet to come up with a solution.

How can I get autocomplete working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being related to a non-portable path in an import, which was breaking Intellisense. My team has a large project with several other projects included as libraries. The main project would include one of them with:

```
#import "LibraryName/LibraryName.h"
```

In one instance, the library project was also performing this same import. I fixed this by having the library import the specific headers it needed from itself.

```
#import "LibraryComponent.h"
#import "NSString+LibraryCategory.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

I am also having same problem, autocomplete is not working in my project. I have gone through following steps. And it worked

1. Open your file/class in xcode and  `#import Foundation` frameworks
2. Open up build phases of your project in xcode. Add Foundation
   framework

   [image]
3. Now go to your project folder from finder right click on your
   .xcodeproj file.Choose

   > Show Package Contents[image]
4. Now choose select

   > xcuserdata

   and delete the folder inside xcuserdata

[image]

5. After deleting folder in above screenshot. Build your project and
   run. It will now work with autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Must try this its really work for Auto Completion and for the syntax color which get all white.

1. First of all in your class ( import Foundation ).
2. Click on the name of your project and go to build phase.
3. Now go to the libaries and add Foundation.framework by click on the + sign you will get the option.
4. Now go to your project folder and right click on workspace file and select Show pakage Contant.
5. right click on Xcuser and delete the file in it.
6. Now clean build the project and quit the Xcode.

> > Now run the project and it will work << :)